# jquery .on() click and :not

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on('click', 'body:not(.add-to)', function(e){
    //$('.tooltip').hide();
    console.log('clik');
});
```

Using the above, wherever I click on the pagem the console.log shows `clik` even when I click the element `.add-to` it fires when it shouldn't.

Have I messed something up?

```
<ul class="user-controls">
    <li>
        <a class="add-to" href="#">
            <img src="/assets/img/icons/add-feed.png" class="favicon">
            <span>Add</span>
        </a>
        <div></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: With that selector, you are saying that the event should be fired when you click on a body which is not .add-to, and I can guess that you don't have a class='add-to' on your <body> tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector `body:not(.add-to)` matches the `<body>` element of the page if it does not expose the `add-to` class. It will not match any of its descendants.

You may be looking for:

```
$(document).on('click', 'body :not(.add-to)', function(e) {
    console.log('click');
});
```

But in that case, the `body` ancestor is not required, and you only have to write:

```
$(document).on('click', ':not(.add-to)', function(e) {
    console.log('click');
});
```

**EDIT:** From the markup you have posted, it becomes clear that a click on the `<img>` or `<span>` elements will trigger the handler, since none of these elements expose the `add-to` class themselves.

You can work around this issue by applying [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to [e.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest(".add-to").length) {
        console.log("click");
    }
});
```

Note that passing `:not(.add-to *)` to `on()` will have nearly the same result, but not quite: that selector will not prevent the call to `console.log()` from being executed if the `<a>` element has text content and that content is clicked.

The solution based on `closest()`, on the other hand, does prevent `console.log()` from being executed in these circumstances.

Comment: this still fires the console.log

Comment: @Beardy, it should not, unless the event is triggered by a descendant of an element matching `.add-to`, but not matching `.add-to` itself. Can you post a sample of your markup and/or reproduce the problem in a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

Add a space between body to get decendents

```
$(document).on('click', 'body :not(.add-to)', function(e){
    //$('.tooltip').hide();
    console.log('clik');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of body there

```
$(document).on('click', ':not(.add-to)', function(e){
    //$('.tooltip').hide();
    console.log('clik');
});
```

As of now you are telling that body that does not have the class `.add-to`

Answer (score 0):

Because your selector matches all `body` elements that does not have `add-to` class.

What you are trying to do is something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'body > *:not(.add-to)', function(e){
    console.log('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between `body` and `:not(.add-to)` otherwise you are telling it to exclude body elements with the class `add-to`:

```
$(document).on('click', 'body :not(.add-to)', function(e){
    //$('.tooltip').hide();
    console.log('clik');
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/UF44p/